# Persistance of sensitive data in Zend

Tags: zend-framework, session, caching, persistence

I'm new to PHP and Zend, and I would like to cache sensitive data about a logged user. The problem is that I don't want the user to be able to change values of this data, so I don't know how to store it.

I wanted to store it in Zend_Register once the user has logged in, but I don't think this is the right solution.

```
Zend_Registry::set('ud', $userData);
```

Then I retrieve the data in another controller :

```
$ud = Zend_Registry::get('ud');
```

Is there another way to do this ? like storing the values in cookies, and checking their integrity with a hash, or setting-up a server-side cache per session...

Thanks in advance,
Jerec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use Zend_Session

```
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('sensetive_data');
$session->name = 'User';
$session->email = 'Email@email.com';
```

Now the interessting part, to take care of integrity you could use some kind of hash.. (not sure if this a good solution?). But if the server is **configured correct**, the session should be save..

Comment: I chose a different way with the sessions but thank you for your answer, I may use it for different purposes later. I use Zend_Session::regenerateId(); and put this ID the the user row in the database. I think the probabilities of generating the same session Id are slight

Answer (score 3):

`Zend_Registry` is not persistent and it's purpose is for sharing temporary data within the application and is lost after script is finished.

If you want persistent data, use [`Zend_Session`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.basic_usage.html)